macOS updates always stop with 9 minutes remaining
For over a year, when I update macOS, at some point the screen goes black. When I hit a key to wake up the computer I see the user login screen appear. When I login the installation is suspended with “9 minutes remaining.” It's the same for every macOS update or upgrade for over a year now. I didn't bother researching thinking it had something to do with my Intel iMac and it's EFI since modern macs don't have an EFI anymore. I can't imagine it's the timing of the screensaver because what are the odds the install would take exactly the same amount of time for every update over the past year.
Is this normal, a security feature requiring the user to verify they own the system before installing the last component or an iCloud requirement?
I started an update today and went out for a few hours hopeful that on my return I would see the install completed... nope. I logged in and there was “9 minutes remaining” with a progress bar and white Apple logo.

Please boot in Recovery mode to install the OS. Make sure you have good backups of all data you want to keep.

I spoke to an Apple Senior Advisor and his 2015 MacBook does this too, but at 39 minutes remaining.

@LincDavis Terrible advice.

That means you tried it and it didn’t work, or you came up with a better solution. Would you like to share it?

@LincDavis Apparently there is no solution - it's a part of the install process on intel macs. When an Apple Senior Tech says it's just the way it is I take him at his word. Have you experienced this and your advice resolved it? That is a very time consuming process to suggest to someone without knowing whether it will resolve the issue. I will leave the question up for now.

Yes, I've known it to work. If it doesn't, it's a step toward isolating the cause of the problem. I'm absolutely sure that not every Intel Mac has the same issue. But I'll stop wasting your time now.
